# In SQL Server can I format the way the date is presented?

Tags: sql-server

I have a datetime column but I want to make the date appear in a special way.

For example it shows like this now:

```
2017-02-01 08:05:01
```

What I would like is for the date to look like this:

```
Feb 02 08:05
```

Can I do this inside a select statement for the column InitDate

Comment: Dates have no format. The best place to format data is at the presentation layer - either on the report field or the textbox or label control you want to use. You perform some limited formatting with the [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) command but don't expect all the features of `String.Format`

Comment: Yes, and the different ways to format them are well documented in the SO Documentation:  [Using `FORMAT()` (SQL Server 2012+)](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1471/dates/8084/date-time-formatting-using-format#t=201702011343248539015) and [Using `CONVERT()`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1471/dates/4801/date-time-formatting-using-convert#t=201702011343248539015)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sql server 2012+ you can use [**`format()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
select format(getdate(),'MMM dd HH:mm') --24 hour format
select format(getdate(),'MMM dd hh:mmtt') --12 hour format with AM|PM
```

Prior to sql server 2012 you can use [**`convert()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
select convert(varchar(20),getdate(),100) -- mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)
```

Comment: hh will return the 12 hour vs HH for the 24 hour.   You could add tt for AM/PM

Comment: Another good resource is the in-house [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1471/dates#t=201702011346334811609).

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Nice catch! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select left(replace(CONVERT( CHAR(12),GETDATE(),107) ,',',''),6)+
 ' '+left(CONVERT( CHAR(50),GETDATE(),108),5)
```

Comment: [“Try this” answers are not useful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/4642212). Please explain how to approach the OP’s problem.